# how can I extract pores from an input binary fingerprint image using marker control watershed segmentation in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, feature-detection, watershed

I am working on pore extraction from  binary fingerprint image, On using the watershed segmentation, I managed to get the gradient image but now I want to extract the pores(white blobs) from the ridges(the lines across the fingerprint).How do I go about?

Comment: Your question may be too complex to be answered, it may help if you could give some overview of what you already tried and where your problems start. There are entire articles on the topic, perhaps [this one](http://de.scribd.com/doc/105723602/Fingerprint-Matching-Approach-Based-on-Bifurcation-Minutiae#scribd) may help you get started.

Comment: Thank you but my query is beyond minutiae and bifurcation. I am doing pores extraction from fingerprint image by using Marker Controlled Watershed Segmentation method proposed by S. Malathi et al. Unfortunately I cant share images due to the preconditions of the group.

Comment: This might elaborate my query [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209308/white-pixels-cluster-extraction)